# How to convert Map<String, String> whose value is json to POJO

Tags: java, jackson

For example our target type is `Info` with following definition

```java
class Info {
  Person person;
  // a dozen of other properties
  // getters and setters
}

class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  // getters and setters
}
```

and our Map is like `Collections.singletonMap("person", "{\"name\": \"nick\", \"age\": 18}")`

How can I convert this Map to `Info` object? (adding a constructor for `Person` or parsing value one by one is not viable because there are actually a dozen of properties like Person.)

Tried using jackson with `objectMapper.convertValue` but it throw a Exception with message `no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value`

Comment: The value is just JSON, parse that part with a JSON parser.

Comment: @Sweeper the thing is I got plenty of properties like person, parse them one by one is not appropriate.

Comment: I see that you tried using Jackson, which _is_ a JSON parser.

Comment: Yes, I would like to deserialize  `Info` as a whole instead of deserializing its properties separately and inject them into info, because there are too many properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson's `ObjectMapper` knows how to convert a `Map` into a `POJO`, but it cannot map string with JSON text into a POJO, so you first have to parse the JSON text into something generic (`Map` or `JsonNode` tree).

Basically, convert your `Map<String, String>` into a `Map<String, JsonNode>`.

```
Map<String, String> data = Collections.singletonMap("person", "{\"name\": \"nick\", \"age\": 18}");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> dataTree = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet())
    dataTree.put(entry.getKey(), mapper.readTree(entry.getValue()));
Info info = mapper.convertValue(dataTree, Info.class);

System.out.println("name = " + info.getPerson().getName());
System.out.println("age = " + info.getPerson().getAge());
```

*Output*

```
name = nick
age = 18
```

Comment: This actually occurred to me , but its seems not very efficient, its much better if we can do this in one go like telling jackson: "when srcType is string and targetType is POJO, use `objectMapper.readValue`"

Comment: @NickAllen But that would require the POJO's to be aware of the *format* in which the input to the mapper is presented. --- Besides, the performance of creating `JsonNode` objects is minimal compared to the actual process of parsing the JSON text, so that's a non-issue. The memory requirement of creating `JsonNode` trees for all the `Info` properties might be an issue, but really, how much memory would that me for one `Info` object? I'd say that's a non-issue too. I think you're worrying about nothing. Beware premature optimization, so just go with the simple code here.

Comment: Just go through jackson's source code, customizing converting behavior like I said is way too complex, I will go with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a `Map<String, String>`, with the key being your field name and value being a `json` structure, there is no other chance than:

```
switch (map.getKey()) { 
    case "person": 
           Person person = mapper.readValue(map.getValue(), Person.class);
           info.setPerson(person);
           break;
    //TODO add your other Map-Keys here
}
```

But if you have a normal json structure like:

```
{
   "person": {
      "name": "nick",
      "age": 18
   }
}
```

Then you could simply:

```
Info info = mapper.readValue(json, Info.class);
```

Comment: Unfortunately we only have a  `Map<String, String>` which is returned from jedis hgetall operation, this is really a headache.

Comment: Then you'd have to create a mapping class yourself, similar to the `switch` case above. Or use reflection to detect the field name, if the target field is always within the `Info.class`?

Comment: Use reflection is a good idea, I am trying to customize the valueSerialize used by jackson, if that didnt work maybe I will go with reflection.

Comment: Otherwise answer from @Andreas is also a nice idea and would certainly work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with Gson library which is created by Google for handling the json structures.

```
Map<String, String> data = Collections.singletonMap("person", "{\"name\": \"nick\", \"age\": 18}");
Person person = new Gson.fromJson(data.get("person"), Person.class);
Info info = new Info();
info.setPerson(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after going through source code, I came up with a solution:

### First, customize a BeanDeserialzier

```
class StringBeanDeserializer extends BeanDeserializer {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    public StringBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerBuilder builder, BeanDescription beanDesc, BeanPropertyMap properties, Map<String, SettableBeanProperty> backRefs, HashSet<String> ignorableProps, boolean ignoreAllUnknown, boolean hasViews, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(builder, beanDesc, properties, backRefs, ignorableProps, ignoreAllUnknown, hasViews);
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper == null ? new ObjectMapper() : objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserializeFromString(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (this._beanType.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(CharSequence.class)) {
            return super.deserializeFromString(p, ctxt);
        }
        return objectMapper.readValue(p.getText(), this._beanType.getRawClass());
    }
}
```

### Then write a Builder to produce that BeanDeserialzier

```
class StringBeanDeserializerBuilder extends BeanDeserializerBuilder {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    public StringBeanDeserializerBuilder(BeanDescription beanDesc, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        super(beanDesc, ctxt);
    }

    public StringBeanDeserializerBuilder(BeanDescription beanDesc, DeserializationContext ctxt, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this(beanDesc, ctxt);
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    protected StringBeanDeserializerBuilder(BeanDeserializerBuilder src) {
        super(src);
    }

    /**
     * Method for constructing a {@link BeanDeserializer}, given all
     * information collected.
     */
    public JsonDeserializer<?> build()
    {
        Collection<SettableBeanProperty> props = _properties.values();
        _fixAccess(props);
        BeanPropertyMap propertyMap = BeanPropertyMap.construct(props,
                _config.isEnabled(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES),
                _collectAliases(props));
        propertyMap.assignIndexes();

        // view processing must be enabled if:
        // (a) fields are not included by default (when deserializing with view), OR
        // (b) one of properties has view(s) to included in defined
        boolean anyViews = !_config.isEnabled(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        if (!anyViews) {
            for (SettableBeanProperty prop : props) {
                if (prop.hasViews()) {
                    anyViews = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // one more thing: may need to create virtual ObjectId property:
        if (_objectIdReader != null) {
            /* 18-Nov-2012, tatu: May or may not have annotations for id property;
             *   but no easy access. But hard to see id property being optional,
             *   so let's consider required at this point.
             */
            ObjectIdValueProperty prop = new ObjectIdValueProperty(_objectIdReader, PropertyMetadata.STD_REQUIRED);
            propertyMap = propertyMap.withProperty(prop);
        }

        return new StringBeanDeserializer(this,
                _beanDesc, propertyMap, _backRefProperties, _ignorableProps, _ignoreAllUnknown,
                anyViews, objectMapper);
    }
}
```

### Finally write a Factory use that Builder

```
public class StringBeanDeserializeFactory extends BeanDeserializerFactory {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    /**
     * Globally shareable thread-safe instance which has no additional custom deserializers
     * registered
     */
    public final static BeanDeserializerFactory instance = new StringBeanDeserializeFactory(
            new DeserializerFactoryConfig());

    public StringBeanDeserializeFactory(DeserializerFactoryConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    /**
     * Overridable method that constructs a {@link BeanDeserializerBuilder}
     * which is used to accumulate information needed to create deserializer
     * instance.
     */
    protected BeanDeserializerBuilder constructBeanDeserializerBuilder(DeserializationContext ctxt,
                                                                       BeanDescription beanDesc) {
        return new StringBeanDeserializerBuilder(beanDesc, ctxt, objectMapper);
    }
}
```

### Example Usage:

```
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(null, null, new DefaultDeserializationContext.Impl(StringBeanDeserializeFactory.instance));
        Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of("person", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Person("nick", 25)),
                "raw", "test");
        System.out.println(objectMapper.convertValue(map, Data.class));
```